# define a generic variable and change it dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, repository

Hi I made a GenericRepository in order to query to database and grab data.
I want to define a variable of this generic repository and change the Type with a switch. something like this:

```
IGenericRepository<object> genericRepository;
```

and for example in load method:

```
switch (table)
            {
                case AvailableTables.Customer:
                    genericRepository = new GenericRepository<Customer>(db.Context);
                    break;
                case AvailableTables.Factor:
                    genericRepository = new GenericRepository<Factor>(db.Context);
                    break;
            }
```

I thought `object` will work but it didn't. 
Can you help me to achieve that?

Comment: Use generics instead of object by using T as the type in all places that you would return the specific object.  First google result comes up with this tutorial http://web.archive.org/web/20150404154203/https://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/

Comment: You could define one more interface - `IGenericRepository` - and have `IGenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository`.  Then you define `IGenericRepository genericRepository` where it doesn't have to define a Type at compile time.

Comment: A given variable's type is defined at _compile time_. The exception being when the variable uses a generic type parameter as part of its declaration. There are a number of possible ways to address what you seem to be looking for, but none will work like the code you posted. See duplicates. The best approach will come down to whether you need to use the object as the specific type (e.g. `IGenericRepository<Customer>`) or if all you really need is to know it's _some_ kind of `IGenericRepository`. If the latter, a base interface as in @jimnkey's suggestion should work fine. If the former, ...

Comment: ... you'll need to extend the use of the generic type parameter to all of the code that is dealing with that particular type.